Windows 2022 Terminal Server running but not listening on fresh syspreped image. Finish setup via commands?
ive got a Windows 2022 coming up from a sysprep-image. On console it waits for some initial questions to be done for localisation, license acceptance and Administrator password. However, meanwhile I use an existing admin user via ansible in the background to setup many things.
Also setting up RDP service. The service is then also running and port is open on firewall.
BUT I can not login as nothing is listening on the port.
As soon I went throught the initial questions on console, it does some magic and then it works. Did not find any hint in syslog.
What is Windows doing here? Can I do the same via ansible/powershell? How can I make RDP to work already before finishing the initial steps?
I also set a Administrator pwd via ansible.
Before someone is asking, I did already those settings:
- name: Enable Remote Desktop via Group Policy registry
  ansible.windows.win_regedit:
    path: HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services
    name: fDenyTSConnections
    data: 0
    type: dword


- name: Ensure RDP binds to port 3389
  ansible.windows.win_regedit:
    path: HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp
    name: PortNumber
    data: 3389
    type: dword

- name: Disable Network Level Authentication (NLA)
  ansible.windows.win_regedit:
    path: HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp
    name: UserAuthentication
    data: 0
    type: dword

- name: Enable RDP through the registry
  ansible.windows.win_regedit:
    path: HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server
    name: fDenyTSConnections
    data: 0
    type: dword

Can i perform the initial Windows-question session via command line, so it's finishing the setup?

I did not find a solution yet but a great Video how to make an unattend file that works. Before I spent weeks with no luck. This one did the job: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSvrFmapbqo
